How to produce a stable mathematical symbol & in the typewriter font?
First a minimal working sample is as follows.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\ttand{\mathord{\texttt{\&}}}

\begin{document}

$\ttand$

\itshape$\ttand$

\end{document}


As you see I defined a mathematical symbol & in the typewriter font. But it isn't stable since it could be effected by \itshape, \bfseries and so on. Furthermore, it does't work by replacing \texttt by \mathtt since \mathtt doesn't work on &. Then how to produce a stable mathematical symbol & in the typewriter font?

You could consider wrapping the ampersand around with \textnormal, then changing the font to monospace inside to prevent interference from other font commands inside the same scope. This ensures the ampersand is always typeset as medium weight, upright, and monospace.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\ttand}{\mathord{\textnormal{\ttfamily\&}}}

\begin{document}

\itshape $\ttand$ % shape

\bfseries$\ttand$ % weight

\sffamily$\ttand$ % family

\sffamily\scshape\bfseries$\ttand$ % or even all three!

\end{document}


Hi @M.Logic, I don’t answer questions to get recognition, so I’m happy even if I don’t get credit in your book. Otherwise, my username will do fine.

I'd use \mathtt.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\ttand{\mathtt{\mathchar\inteval{"7000+`\&}}}

\begin{document}

text $\ttand$ text

\textit{text $\ttand$ text}

\end{document}

Explanation: we want to get a symbol that respects the current math group, so its math code should be "70xx, where "xx is the ASCII code of &. Since I'm lazy to look the latter up, I use simple arithmetic. 

Maybe cleaner:
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathampersand}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`\&}

\newcommand*\ttand{\mathtt{\mathampersand}}

\begin{document}

text $\ttand$ text

\textit{text $\ttand$ text}

$\mathampersand+\mathtt{\mathampersand}+\mathit{\mathampersand}+\mathsf{\mathampersand}$

\end{document}



The ASCII code of & is "26.
